# Farm member registering failed for node with server ID "mobileserver1" In MobileFirst platform v7.1

Tags: mobilefirst-server

I am having MFP 7.1 server Farm setup with below configuration

```
WAS Liberty v8.5.5.7
java 1.8.0
MFP v7.1
```

After Deploying the project WAR file we started all the MFP nodes. I got the below error message :

> [2/13/18 10:22:21:330 GST] 000000cb
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.ManagementMXBeanImpl  E Farm member
>   registering failed for a node with server ID "mobileserver1" for
>   runtime "ADIBMBA". com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.
>   ConflictException: FWLSE3200W: The server "ADIBMBA" cannot be added as
>   a new farm member because a server with the same ID is already
>   registered for the runtime "mobileserver1".

But as I can see there is not any node having the same ID. so what else could be the reason for this please let me know ??

Answer (score 1):

Check the following documentation link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_server_farm_setup.html

The following JNDI property in liberty server.xml should have a unique value : ibm.worklight.admin.serverid

This identifier is defined for this farm member. This identifier must be unique across all farm members. In your case the "ibm.worklight.admin.serverid" property in each node may be named "mobileserver1","mobileserver2", "mobileserver3" etc.

Hope this helps.